# Rake db:seed not associating a created object to it's parent model correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake

I have a User model which has_one Library which has_many Books.

In my seeds file I do this:

```
user1 = User.new
user1.email = "test@email.com"
user1.name  = "testname"
user1.password = "password"
user1.library = Library.new
user1.library.save!
book1 = Book.create!(hash_of_attributes)
user1.library.books << book1
puts "book1 library_id " + book1.library_id.to_s
user1.save!
```

the line puts "book1 library_id " + book1.library_id.to_s clearly outputs the value of 1, so we know the library_id attribute is set to 1 on the newly created Book model.

However, after running rake db:seed, I run rails console and do:

```
User.first.library.books
```

only to find

```
<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

And running Book.first shows

```
 library_id: nil
```

So the book was created except it wasn't properly associated to my library, which is properly associated to my user model.

What is going on?

Running Rails 4.1.6

Comment: You need to save user for it's id to become the foreign key of library.

Comment: I tried this(even though they  aren't same model names, but same relationship), but your code work for me.  My Rails' version is 4.1.7, I don't know whether it's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
user1 = User.new
user1.email = "test@email.com"
user1.name  = "testname"
user1.password = "password"
user1.save!
```

First of all you need to save user for it's id. Then ....

```
user1.library = Library.new
library1 = user1.library.save!

book = Book.create!(hash_of_attributes)
book1 = library1.books << book
puts "book1 library_id " + book1.library_id.to_s
```

Comment: saving user before adding books worked, thank you a million this was extremely frustrating. However, I'm curious why this is because books are connected to Library not user, so you would think once a Library is saved and it's ID determined, a book would be able to be set to a library, then the library set to the user?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your user does not have an id by the time you're trying to make associations on it.  Just a quick update to the script and you should be good to go:

```
user1 = User.create(email: "test@email.com", name: "testname", password: "password")
user1.library.create
user1.library.books.create(hash_of_attributes)
```